# Java GUI Components and Panel Alignment

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I'm quite new to Java GUI and I'm having trouble aligning the GUI of this program I created . The code is as follow :

#### The Code :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
public class SalesScreen{

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

//Top Member Panel
private JPanel memberPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
private JLabel memberID =  new JLabel();
private JTextField memberIDField = new JTextField(10);
private JLabel memberName = new JLabel();
private JTextField memberNameField = new JTextField(30);
private JButton memberButton = new JButton("OK");

//Center Table Panel
private JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
private JTable itemList;
String [] columnNames = {"Barcode" , "Name" , "Price (RM)" , "Quantity"};
int numRows = 30;
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(numRows , columnNames.length);
JScrollPane scroll;

//Bottom Right 
private JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JPanel infoGridPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(4,2));
private JPanel infoFlowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
private JLabel total = new JLabel("          Total (RM) :");
private JLabel discount = new JLabel("          Discount Rate (%) : ");
private JLabel overall = new JLabel("          Overall (RM) :");
private JLabel payment = new JLabel("          Payment (RM) :");
private JButton process = new JButton("PROCESS");
private JTextField totalPrice = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField discountRate = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField overallPrice = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField paymentMade = new JTextField(5);

//Bottom
private JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2 , 4 , 4 , 20));
private JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
private JLabel emptyLabel2 = new JLabel("");
private JLabel barcode = new JLabel("Enter Barcode :");
private JTextField barcodeScanner = new JTextField(5);
private JLabel quantity = new JLabel("Quantity :");
private JTextField itemQuantity = new JTextField(5);
private JButton addItem = new JButton("Add");
private JButton deleteItem = new JButton("Delete");

    //                                           //
   //                                           //
  //    Beginning of Constructor and Method    //
 //                                           //
//                                           //

SalesScreen(JTabbedPane tabp , JFrame f) //tabp is Jtabbedpanel , f is the Jframe
{
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    memberID.setText("          Member ID :");
    memberIDField.setText("");
    memberName.setText("Member Name :");
    memberNameField.setText("");
    memberNameField.setEditable(false);
    memberPanel.add(memberID);
    memberPanel.add(memberIDField);
    memberPanel.add(memberName);
    memberPanel.add(memberNameField);
    memberPanel.add(memberButton);
    //
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    itemList = new JTable(model);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(itemList); 
    //tablePanel.add(scroll);
    //
    total.setLabelFor(totalPrice);
    totalPrice.setEditable(false);
    discountRate.setEditable(false);
    overallPrice.setEditable(false);
    process.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    discount.setLabelFor(discountRate);
    overall.setLabelFor(overallPrice);
    payment.setLabelFor(paymentMade);
    infoGridPanel.add(total);
    infoGridPanel.add(totalPrice);
    infoGridPanel.add(discount);
    infoGridPanel.add(discountRate);
    infoGridPanel.add(overall);
    infoGridPanel.add(overallPrice);
    infoGridPanel.add(payment);
    infoGridPanel.add(paymentMade);
    infoFlowPanel.add(infoGridPanel);
    infoFlowPanel.add(process);
    infoPanel.add(infoFlowPanel , "South");
    //

    testPanel.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(  100, 100) );
    testPanel.add(barcode);
    testPanel.add(barcodeScanner);
    testPanel.add(addItem);
    testPanel.add(deleteItem);
    testPanel.add(quantity);
    testPanel.add(itemQuantity);
    testPanel.add(emptyLabel);
    testPanel.add(emptyLabel2);
    itemPanel.add(testPanel , "West");
    //
    mainPanel.add(memberPanel , "North");
    mainPanel.add(scroll , "Center");
    mainPanel.add(infoPanel , "East");
    mainPanel.add(itemPanel , "South");
    tabp.add("Sales" , mainPanel); 
    f.add(tabp);
}
```

}

**The Question :**

1.)As you can see , there will be a Jtable at the center , a JPanel at bottom right panel and also one at the bottom . What I wanna do is to eliminate the empty space available at the end of the Jtable  by moving the bottom panel slightly above . I keep try and try to no avail .

Comment: Please clarify your question by re-stating your problem and what you're unsuccessfully trying to do? And why your attempts aren't working.

Comment: Do you call `pack()` on your JFrame *after* adding all components to it and *before* calling `setVisible(true)` on it? Are you avoiding the temptation of calling `setSize(...)` on anything and everything?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to move the bottom panel up slightly, you can simply reduce the vertical gap in the `GridLayout` for `testPanel`. Replace

```
private JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2 , 4 , 4 , 20));
```

with

```
private JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4, 4, 5));
```

Also better to override `getPreferredSize()` for components rather than calling `setPreferredSize`. This ensures that the preferred size cannot be set by another component.

Calling `JFrame.pack` will complete the task by sizing the window by arranging all the components according to their preferred sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
class SalesScreen{

private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

//Top Member Panel
private JPanel memberPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
private JLabel memberID =  new JLabel();
private JTextField memberIDField = new JTextField(10);
private JLabel memberName = new JLabel();
private JTextField memberNameField = new JTextField(30);
private JButton memberButton = new JButton("OK");

//Center Table Panel
private JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
private JTable itemList;
String [] columnNames = {"Barcode" , "Name" , "Price (RM)" , "Quantity"};
int numRows = 50;
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(numRows , columnNames.length);
JScrollPane scroll;

//Bottom Right 
private JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JPanel infoGridPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(4,2));
private JPanel infoFlowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
private JLabel total = new JLabel("          Total (RM) :");
private JLabel discount = new JLabel("          Discount Rate (%) : ");
private JLabel overall = new JLabel("          Overall (RM) :");
private JLabel payment = new JLabel("          Payment (RM) :");
private JButton process = new JButton("PROCESS");
private JTextField totalPrice = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField discountRate = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField overallPrice = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField paymentMade = new JTextField(5);

//Bottom
private JPanel itemPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
private JPanel testPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2 , 4 , 4 , 20));
private JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
private JLabel emptyLabel2 = new JLabel("");
private JLabel barcode = new JLabel("Enter Barcode :");
private JTextField barcodeScanner = new JTextField(5);
private JLabel quantity = new JLabel("Quantity :");
private JTextField itemQuantity = new JTextField(5);
private JButton addItem = new JButton("Add");
private JButton deleteItem = new JButton("Delete");

    //                                           //
   //                                           //
  //    Beginning of Constructor and Method    //
 //                                           //
//                                           //

SalesScreen(JTabbedPane tabp , JFrame f) //tabp is Jtabbedpanel , f is the Jframe
{
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    memberID.setText("          Member ID :");
    memberIDField.setText("");
    memberName.setText("Member Name :");
    memberNameField.setText("");
    memberNameField.setEditable(false);
    memberPanel.add(memberID);
    memberPanel.add(memberIDField);
    memberPanel.add(memberName);
    memberPanel.add(memberNameField);
    memberPanel.add(memberButton);
    //
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    itemList = new JTable(model);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(itemList); 
    //tablePanel.add(scroll);
    //
    total.setLabelFor(totalPrice);
    totalPrice.setEditable(false);
    discountRate.setEditable(false);
    overallPrice.setEditable(false);
    process.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    discount.setLabelFor(discountRate);
    overall.setLabelFor(overallPrice);
    payment.setLabelFor(paymentMade);
    infoGridPanel.add(total);
    infoGridPanel.add(totalPrice);
    infoGridPanel.add(discount);
    infoGridPanel.add(discountRate);
    infoGridPanel.add(overall);
    infoGridPanel.add(overallPrice);
    infoGridPanel.add(payment);
    infoGridPanel.add(paymentMade);
    infoFlowPanel.add(infoGridPanel);
    infoFlowPanel.add(process);
    infoPanel.add(infoFlowPanel , "South");
    //

    testPanel.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(  100, 100) );
    testPanel.add(barcode);
    testPanel.add(barcodeScanner);
    testPanel.add(addItem);
    testPanel.add(deleteItem);
    testPanel.add(quantity);
    testPanel.add(itemQuantity);
    testPanel.add(emptyLabel);
    testPanel.add(emptyLabel2);
    itemPanel.add(testPanel , "West");
    itemPanel.add(infoPanel , "East");
    //
    mainPanel.add(memberPanel , "North");
    mainPanel.add(scroll , "Center");
  //  mainPanel.add(infoPanel , "East");
    mainPanel.add(itemPanel , "South");
    tabp.add("Sales" , mainPanel); 
    f.add(tabp);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
SalesScreen s=new SalesScreen(new JTabbedPane(),new JFrame("test"));
}
}
```

Try this code..